# Force assignment of undefined with strict null checks enabled?

Tags: typescript

I'm taking a look at enabling the `strictNullChecks` flag for a TypeScript project I've been working on, but it creates *a lot* of compiler errors.  Some of them are edge cases I genuinely need to check but a lot of them fall into a particular pattern.

```
type BusinessObject = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  requiredValue: number;
  // ...
}

class DataStore {
  // ...
  public addItem(item: BusinessObject): Promise<string>;
  public getItem(id: string): Promise<BusinessObject>;
}

function consumeData(store: DataStore){
  store.addItem({name:"one", requiredValue:1});
  store.getItem("two").then(item => console.log(item.id));
}
```

The problem is that the `id` property is created by the backing database, so it's only "optional" when making a new item.  If I make the `id` property required (no `?:`), I get a compiler error in the call to `addItem`.  But if I make the ID property optional, then every reference to it has to include a guard or [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (`item.id!`).

The least bad solution I've been able to come up with so far is to cast the argument I pass to `addItem` as `any` but this disables checking on the other properties of the `BusinessObject`, so it's not a great solution.  What I'm hoping for is a sort of analog to the non-null assertion operator, that lets me assert that a null assignment is OK, even though the type declaration says that it isn't: something like `store.addItem({id: undefined!, name:"one", requiredValue:1});`.

I would also welcome a better / more consistent way of describing this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two types, one representing the object when creating, and one representing a saved object

```
type NewBusinessObject = {
    id?: string;
    name: string;
    requiredValue: number;
    // ...
}
type BusinessObject = NewBusinessObject & {
    id: string
}

declare class DataStore {
    // ...
    public addItem(item: NewBusinessObject): Promise<string>;
    public getItem(id: string): Promise<BusinessObject>;
}

function consumeData(store: DataStore) {
    store.addItem({ name: "one", requiredValue: 1 });
    store.getItem("two").then(item => console.log(item.id));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that there is an operator that works more or less as I described:

```
store.addItem({ id: undefined as any, name: "one", requiredValue: 1 });
```

I'd still like better long term solutions, like Titian's suggestion, but this is at least an option.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to avoid the error would be to change the definition of `addItem` to:

```
public addItem(item: Partial<BusinessObject>): Promise<string>
```

the code will now work, although it makes all of the properties of BusinessObject optional, not just the `id`. That might not be a problem if you have sensible defaults for all of the other properties, but otherwise you have to fall back on creating two types with and without the `id`.

What you really want of course is something like:

```
public addItem(item: Omit<BusinessObject, "id">): Promise<string>
```

There are several proposals for something like this in typescript (e.g. see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215) so there is hope that your code can be simplified in the future.

There's a lot in that issue, so to save you reading all the way through it, here's what seems to work (see also issue 19569):

```
export type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P} &
  {[P in U]: never} & {[x: string]: never})[T];
export type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>;

type BusinessObject = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  requiredValue: number;
  // ...
}

class DataStore {
  // ...
  public addItem(item: Omit<BusinessObject, "id">): Promise<string> {
      return Promise.resolve('foo')};
  public getItem(id: string): Promise<BusinessObject> {
      return Promise.resolve({} as any as BusinessObject);
  };
}

function consumeData(store: DataStore){
  store.addItem({name:"one", requiredValue:1});
  store.getItem("two").then(item => console.log(item.id));
}
```

(dummy body code added for `addItem` and `getItem` to keep the compiler happy, just ignore that.)

Comment: This is the first I've seen `Partial` mentioned, very helpful to know about.  Thanks!

Comment: @Coderer I edited my answer to include a suggested definition of `Omit` from the long discussion.